# What are the procedures and protocols to use with Gauss'method and personal observations?

Tags: astrophysics, observational-astronomy

I would like to use the [Gauss' method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27_method) to determine the orbit of planets of solar system.

I would like to calculate their orbits with personal observations.

What is the methodology/procedure/protocol to follow?

What data do I need to measure during my observations?